# How would I place CAN termination resistors in a 3 ended configuration?

Tags: digital-logic, can, bus, termination, serial-bus

I have a project for which I have one central circuit board which has a can node on it, this central circuit board has three connectors on each of which a node could or could not be plugged in with a cable (max. 2m). A simple diagram of the setup would look something like this:

[image]

Any off the connectors could or could not be connected to a node depending on how many peripherals are connected. And FYI the nodes are never connected or unconnected while the system is running.

My question is, where would I place termination resistors and why would I put them where you suggest ?

Thanks for all answers in advance.

Comment: Baud rate is critical information for this setup.

Comment: 1 Mb/s Baud is what I am planing on using

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CAN was designed to be a bus, not a star topology network. Because of this non standard configuration it might be difficult to get the speeds that you want due to reflections, but because of the short line length of 2m, each line could be considered a drop, and the recommended limit for drops at 1Mbps is 2m.

[image]
Source: [Elektromotus CAN bus topology recommendations
v0.2 rc2](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=2ahUKEwiK_8eV_LbhAhXYs54KHWyFBo4QFjABegQICxAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.elektromobilitaet-riester.de%2Fapp%2Fdownload%2F14336296225%2FElektromotus_CAN_bus_recommendations_v0.2_rc3.pdf%3Ft%3D1542113205&usg=AOvVaw3WVV2PPwPs2I0O-dTkJHJX)

Add the option to terminate the devices by adding a resistor, then experiment. I would terminate only one device, only one termination resistor is needed in a CAN network, check the ringing on the lines.  If there is too much ringing it might be beneficial to add two termination resistors on two of the devices and experiment with the configuration.

More than two resistors is not recommended because it exceeds the rated load on most transceivers.

> There should be no more than two terminating resistors in the network,
>   regardless of how many nodes are connected, because additional
>   terminations place extra load on the CAN transceivers.

Source:  [Elektromotus CAN bus topology recommendations
v0.2 rc2](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=2ahUKEwiK_8eV_LbhAhXYs54KHWyFBo4QFjABegQICxAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.elektromobilitaet-riester.de%2Fapp%2Fdownload%2F14336296225%2FElektromotus_CAN_bus_recommendations_v0.2_rc3.pdf%3Ft%3D1542113205&usg=AOvVaw3WVV2PPwPs2I0O-dTkJHJX)